# ssh crashes after login

Tags: ssh, scp

unfortunately ssh hangs up after login. Already uninstalled and installed it again. I can fix the issue temporary by erasing ~/.ssh and logoff and login on my system again.

Here is my ssh -v dump:

```
OpenSSH_5.8p1 Debian-7ubuntu1, OpenSSL 1.0.0e 6 Sep 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to host [ip] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/<user>/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/<user>/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/<user>/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/<user>/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/<user>/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/<user>/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.5p1 Debian-6
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.5p1 Debian-6 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.8p1 Debian-7ubuntu1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: <key>
debug1: Host 'host' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/<user>/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/<user>/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/<user>/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/<user>/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Next authentication method: password
user@host's password:
debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
Authenticated to host ([ip]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LC_MESSAGES = de_DE.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_COLLATE = de_DE.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LANG = de_DE.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_CTYPE = de_DE.UTF-8
```

Does anybody have a clue?  'cause I am clueless...

Thanks in advance

EDIT: Also I want to mention that the terminal seems to hangup completely because Ctrl + C or Ctrl + X don't work.

EDIT2: I also tried ssh -v host ls and the dump looks exactly the same except there is

```
debug1: Sending command: ls
```

at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the problem - it was a corrupted wlan-router/dsl-modem combination. With new router and modem everythings works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run `strace ssh ...` to determine what the system is doing when it seems to be hung.

(Please note that strace output contains your password, so do not post it without carefully editing out.)

Comment: here comes the strace dump, unfortunately it was too long, so this is just the part after the login: http://pastebin.com/RYsJcETz

Comment: The last line for me looks like `select(7, [3 4], [], NULL, NULL) = 1 (in [3])` and then continues with a read, a select and finally with the login message. Could you check your `/var/log/auth.log` on your server, if there is any authentication failure?